# Where can I update Installed Package Icons?

Tags: c#

I'm using JetBrains Rider and wondered where in the package the "Installed Packages" icons are referenced from.

Highlighted in red here:

[image: Package Icon Example]

Answer (score 0):

on Linux: /home/"user"/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/"package name"/

on Windows: "package install folder"/lib/icons.jar